# Модальные окна и MVVM

Tags: c#, wpf

Есть приложение построенное по патерну MVVM. Есть **кнопка** в главном окне приложения, которая вызывает **команду**. Эта команда **сохраняет** данные, введённые пользователем. **НО** данные могут не сохранится, если поле ввода потеряет фокус (не важно как).

Чтобы такого не было, при не сохранении данных (потере фокуса) я хочу, чтобы выводилось окошечко по типу: "вы уверены, что хотите потерять данные?" и там кнопочки для сохранения или отмены перехода в другую область. От этих "кнопочек"
будет **зависеть** то, что приложению следует делать дальше: или позволить данным потеряться или вернуть пользователя к вводу данных.

---

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как лучше весь этот процесс с окошечком уложить в среду MVVM?

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Открыть другое окно внутри текущего окна (WPF)](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/848405/%d0%9e%d1%82%d0%ba%d1%80%d1%8b%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%b4%d1%80%d1%83%d0%b3%d0%be%d0%b5-%d0%be%d0%ba%d0%bd%d0%be-%d0%b2%d0%bd%d1%83%d1%82%d1%80%d0%b8-%d1%82%d0%b5%d0%ba%d1%83%d1%89%d0%b5%d0%b3%d0%be-%d0%be%d0%ba%d0%bd%d0%b0-wpf)

Comment: Дубликатом я его назвать не смогу, так как там нет и слова про MVVM. А у меня вопрос стоит на нём...

Comment: MVVM - это подход, где вы разделяете все на слои (Model/ViewModel/View), я вам дал пример того, что вам надо реализовать, остается только создать свойства для привязки и отобразить контрол. Не уж то вы это не в состояние сделать?

Comment: @EvgeniyZ, как реализовать модальное окно я знаю. Я просил советов по тому, как лучше связать это с MVVM. Или вообще всё ровно как это реализовывать (вывод окна и выполнение действий, зависящих от результата окна: нажата кнопка "Выйти всё ровно" или "Остаться"). Не написал это сразу в вопросе. Может поэтому вы думаете, что я спрашиваю тоже самое, что и в том вопросе

Comment: Думаю вопрос https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/727749/wpf-%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%B8%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D0%BE-%D1%81-%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%87%D0%BA%D0%B8-%D0%B7%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F-%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BD%D1%86%D0%B5%D0%BF%D1%86%D0%B8%D0%B8-mvvm-%D0%B2%D1%8B%D0%B7%D1%8B%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%B5-%D0%BE%D0%BA%D0%BD%D0%BE-%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BC%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B4%D0%BE%D0%B9 гораздо больше соответствует теме.

Comment: [Сервис создания модальных и немодальных окон в контексте паттерна MVVM](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/526028/179763)