# Как мне по кнопке открывать контекстное меню по средине окна?

Tags: c#, wpf

Хочу чтобы по кнопке открывалось контекстное меню прямо по средине окна. Не могу придумать как это сделать.

Comment: Контекстное меню - это по правой мышке у контекста. Если я понял, вам нужен Popup и внутри его Menu.

Comment: А где он будет хранится ? В кнопке которую нужно нажать ? И я так понимаю что место установки задается свойством PlacementTarget?

Comment: Какую вы задачу решаете? Что вам надо? Почему именно контекстное меню по центру окна? Почему не другое окно, или контрол? Вот к примеру [ответ](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/848418/220553), чем не решение вашей задачи? Просто мне кажется, что вы не те инструменты выбрали, ведь контекстное меню не предназначено для того, чтоб оно просто так открывалось по кнопке (хотя это можно...).

Comment: Я копирую дизайн телеграмма. И мне нужно всплывающее окно для редактирования или настроек

Comment: И мне нужно конкретно поверх главного окна

Comment: Это называется диалог с менюшечкой или с настройками, но не контекстное меню. Я бы Grid разместил по центру и контент в него засунул. Просто создайте 2 грида в окне, второму просто включайте и выключайте `Visibility`. `<Grid><Grid>...основное</Grid><Grid Visibility="Hidden">...попап</Grid></Grid>`

Comment: Во, нашел пример https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1222168/373567, там попапчик с надписью выскакивает, в попапчик можно что угодно положить, нет огрничений.

Comment: Так что все же лучше ? Через гриды или через Popup?